# Javascript Button in clock current timing is not working properly

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Clock</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="start()">
<span id="cloc"> </span>
<br><br>
<button onClick="stopclock()"> Stop </button>
<button onClick="start()"> Start </button>


<script>
var my_clock;
function start(){
    my_clock=setInterval(function(){clockstart()},500);
}

function clockstart()
{
    var date= new Date();
    var h= date.getHours();
    var m=date.getMinutes();
    var sec= date.getSeconds();
    hours = ((h<10)? "0" : "" )+ h;
    minute=(m<10)? "0" : "" + m;
    sec= ((sec<10)? "0" : "") + sec;
    sec = sec +( (hours<12)? "  AM" : "  PM" );
    if(hours>12)
    {
        hours=hours-12;
        hours= ((hours<10)? "0" : "") + hours;
    }
    var final_clock= hours +" : "+ minute +" : "+ sec;
    document.getElementById("cloc").innerHTML=final_clock;  
}

function stopclock()
{
    clearInterval(my_clock);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**These codes is working properly... but when i click  on start button 2 times than stop button is not working ... but with single click its working correctly... Can any one help me? **

Comment: You need to `clearInterval` to clear previous one before you add another `setInterval`, otherwise the previous `my_clock` is override by the new one, so it can't be cleared afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

When you click start for 2nd time, your current code will assign a new value to `my_clock`, and create another timer. Then, when you want to stop it, it only stops the latest timer, as you can't reach the id of the previous timer, the previous timer will keep running.

You can either ensure that there's only one timer at a time, or clear previous timer before you create a new one.

Below is how to achieve it with only one timer at a time.

```
// Give it an init value of null.
var my_clock = null;
function start(){
  // Only setInterval if there's no current interval running.
  if (my_clock === null) {
      my_clock = setInterval(function(){clockstart()},500);
  } 
}

function stopclock() {
    // Only clear the interval if there's one running.
    // And set it back to null for another start.
    if (my_clock !== null) {
        clearInterval(my_clock);
        my_clock = null;
    }
}
```